# Resize QTableWidget row and column to size of QWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I created a QTableWidget, filling it with data, it is working well.
I used resizeColumnToContents() and resizeRowsToContents() to adapt the size of columns and rows to their content, which was working well as well.

I needed to add a button to one of the columns, so I created something like that:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *

class Window(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        COLUMNS = 3
        ROWS = 2
        self.setColumnCount(COLUMNS)
        self.setRowCount(ROWS)

        self.setItem(0,0, QTableWidgetItem("Simple line"))
        self.setItem(0,1, QTableWidgetItem("Simple line"))
        self.setItem(1,0, QTableWidgetItem("Multi line\nMulti line\nMulti line"))
        self.setItem(1,1, QTableWidgetItem("Multi line\nMulti line\nMulti line"))

        for i in range(ROWS):
            layout = QVBoxLayout()
            layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
            label = QLabel("Hello guys")
            button = QPushButton("It is a button")
            layout.addWidget(label, 0)
            layout.addWidget(button, 0)

            mainWidget = QWidget()
            mainWidget.setLayout(layout)

            self.setCellWidget(i, 2, mainWidget)

        for i in range(COLUMNS):
            self.resizeColumnToContents(i)
        self.resizeRowsToContents()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(700, 150, 800, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem is that it resizes the rows and columns to the content of the QTableWidget, and not to the size of the QWidget "mainWidget".
So if the size of the row is quite big (several lines of content), it is quite alright.
However, if the size of the row is small (only one line of content), the QWidget is cut.

Example:

[image: Example]

I guess my question is, how to adapt the size of a row to the size of a QWidget instead of the size of it content?

Comment: With the given code, I cannot reproduce the problem as soon as the table is shown (at least on Linux, but it shouldn't change on other platforms). Can you please provide a [mre]?

Comment: @musicamante I edited the question with a (not) working example.
Working in the sense that you can execute the code.
Not working because... it does not reproduce the issue...
My QTableWidget has however a lot more parameters, probably one is in conflict with resize, I need to investigate more.

Comment: The purpose of a MRE is exactly to reproduce the problem, so right not your code is not very useful. Please check your code, try to reduce it until you are not able to reproduce the problem anymore, and if you still don't understand the reason of the issue, then reintroduce the step that creates it and provide *that* example. Check that you're not setting the header sections mode to `Stretch` or `Fixed`, that you don't use `resizeSection` somewhere else, or that you are not overriding any of the `sizeHintFor*` functions or `sizeHint` for a delegate.